# I'm having problems appending the value of a char variable to a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, strcat

I've been trying to use strcat(array, &charVariable) to add charVariable to array,
when i display the array it displays this ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠.
can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `strcat` expects a pointer to a null-terminated character sequence. In your case, you are passing an address of a stand-alone `char` variable. If the item in memory immediately after the `char` variable is not zero, you will trigger undefined behavior (appending garbage characters or crashing).

Here is how to do it correctly:

```
char tmp[2];
tmp[0] = charVariable;
tmp[1] = '\0';
strcat(array, tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` is meant to be used on strings, which have a null byte `\0` at the end.  You can try the approach suggested by dasblinkenlight, but a more efficient approach (assuming `array` has enough space to add the extra char, which you'd have to assume anyway to use `strcat`) is:

```
int len = strlen(array);
array[len] = charVariable;
array[len+1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score -2):

Rules for using `strcat()`:

1. The target string must already have a null character ('\0') terminator, otherwise `strcat()` will not be able to find the end of it.
2. The target string must be big enough to hold the string you are appending to it, in addition to the characters and the terminating null character that it already contains.
3. The source string you are appended to the target string must also have a null terminator, otherwise `strcat()` will not be able to find the end of it.

**Addendum**

@dasblinkenlight gives one proper way to do it. Here is another:

```
size_t  len;
len = strlen(array);
array[len] = charVariable;
array[len+1] = '\0';
```